# UITableView does not load data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, storyboard

I am relative new to iOS development. Right now, I created 2 `ViewController` using storyboard. The one consist one button that lead into another controller using segue (show).

This controller is `TableViewController` that embedded in Navigation Controller and already connected with its responsible class that inherit from `UITableViewController`.

My problem is this page doesn't load its data (`NSMutableArray`) that already initialized in `viewDidLoad` using

```
_dataClient = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"First City",@"Second City",@"Third City",@"Forth City",@"Fift City", nil];
```

This is my table delegate and datasource:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_dataClient count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellItem";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [_dataClient objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Is there any step that I forgot to do?

Comment: don'take -numberOfSectionsInTableView method it will always by default 1,If u want more than 1 section then u can take that this method and return section as u want.

Comment: Yea, I think I rarely use table with section more than one except for static table. But thank you @bhavin ramani.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *must return 1 section* at least. Change this line:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1; /// here
}
```

Comment: Woooah, you saved my life anhtu! Thank you so much!

Comment: 7 minutes remaining :D

Comment: You guys are awesome! Thank you Kumar KL and @anthu