# tableview: cellForRowAtIndexPath is not being called

Tags: ios, tableview, swift2, ios9, xcode7

I can't figure out what is wrong with my `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath`. its never getting called for some reason. i have called the proper delegate and datasource. When I add a `print("")` line under the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, it never appears when i simulate the app.

Thank you in advanced.

here is my code for the whole page:

```
class MainPageViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var sportCells = [PFObject]()


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var profilePictureImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var fullNameLabel: UILabel!





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self

    //Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    updateSportsTable()
    print("its happening")
    let lastName = PFUser.currentUser()! ["last_name"]
    if let firstName = PFUser.currentUser()?["first_name"] as? String {
        self.fullNameLabel.text = "\(firstName) \(lastName)"


    }

    if let userPicture = PFUser.currentUser()?["profile_picture"] as? PFFile {
        userPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                self.profilePictureImageView.image = UIImage(data:imageData!)


            }
        }
    }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("sportCells count is \(sportCells.count)")
    return sportCells.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    print("data extracted1")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("sportCell") as! SportTableViewCell
   print("data extracted")
    let sportPost = self.sportCells[indexPath.row]
    let user = sportPost["user"] as! PFUser
    print("data extracted")
    do {
        try user.fetchIfNeeded()
        print("its happening 3rd time")
    } catch _ {
        print("There was an error")
    }

    cell.sportTitle.text = sportPost["basketballTitle"] as? String
    cell.sportLogo.text = sportPost["basketballLogo"] as? String
    cell.numberOfPOTM.text = "5"
    return cell
}



func updateSportsTable() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Sports")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (sportCells:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print("its happening again")
        }


    }



}
```

Comment: What does `sportCells.count ` prints in `numberOfRowsInSection ` ? Also, if you are adding your table view inside storyboard or XIB, try by deleting the constraints and re-add them.

Comment: sportCells.count prints 0. I assume its because the cellForRowAtIndexPath isn't being called. Ill try deleting the constraints and then re-adding them and see what happens and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: `sportCells.count == 0` -> your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384433/uitableview-does-not-load-data/33384470#33384470

Comment: The issue is with method updateSportsTable(). As you are not saving data in array named "sportCells".

Comment: There you go. `sportCells.count ` must return positive value for your `cellForRowAtIndexPath ` to get called. Ensure you populate `sportCells` properly and that call `self.tableView.reloadData` post that.

Comment: i think I'm missing something here. I completely took out self.tableView.reloadData and it's still giving me issues. How can sportCells be populated if numberOfRowsInSection is not being called? I know I'm probably missing something really simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed from the comments, you problem is data population in model `sportCells`.

Ensure that `sportCells` is populated properly and that you call `self.tableView.reloadData` after that.

Comment: how is sportCells supposed to be populated if it gets populated under cellForRowAtIndexPath? Am I missing a simple idea here...

Comment: i think my issue is with this line: query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (sportCells:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in..... If i try to use [AnyObject] instead of PFObject, Xcode crashes and all the code text turns black...

Comment: You never load your model in `cellForRowAtIndexPath `. Load your data in `viewDidLoad ` and then call `self.tableView.reloadData`.